# aliases in bash shell not working

Tags: macos, alias, bash

I'm running Mavericks on a fresh MBA.

**.bash_aliases**

```
alias la='ls -a'

alias dev='cd ~/Development/Rails'
```

**.bash_profile**

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

**.bashrc**

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

source ~/.bash_aliases
```

I am getting the following message in my fresh shell:

```
-bash: alias: -a: not found

-bash: alias: /Users/david/Development/Rails': not found
```

My quoting isn't working, what is up with this?  Thank you.

Comment: What's the output of `od -c .bash_aliases`?

Comment: My guess is you're using "smart quotes" instead of ASCII single quotes.

Comment: 0000000    a   l   i   a   s       l   a   =   ‘  **  **   l   s       -
0000020    a   ’  **  **  \n  \n   a   l   i   a   s       d   e   v   =
0000040    ‘  **  **   c   d       ~   /   D   e   v   e   l   o   p   m
0000060    e   n   t   /   R   a   i   l   s   ’  **  **                
0000074
@thatotherguy

Comment: please include debug output in  you main question, correctly formatted with the `{}` tool at the top left of the input box. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart quotes were indeed turned on.